# В if всегда true

Tags: php, mysql

Что-то не так, ведь до того как я начал изменять эту строчку такая же конструкция работала правильно, а теперь у меня всегда true при любом значении `$input`, почему так?

```
if ($wrd = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT dict_id FROM dict_word WHERE dict_word='".$input."'")) {
```

Comment: оно не могло работать. mysqli_query вернет false только если будет ошибка в запросе. В нормальной ситуации она возвращает объект mysqli_result из которого и можно прочитать то, что вернул запрос

Comment: @Mike, хм.. наверное неусмотрел. На счет обьекта я знал, но как тогда мне проверять был ли возвращен результат или ничего? `empty()`?

Comment: Видимо проверять $wrd->num_rows. Или использовать какую нибудь из функций fetch_* http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: мне кажется что вообще код сформулирован не правильно, некогда так не делал правда. и наверное не буду :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать как-нибудь так:

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT dict_id FROM dict_word WHERE dict_word='".$input."'");
$count_rows = ($query===false) ? false : mysqli_num_rows($query);
if ($count_rows) {
...
}
```

Comment: Я сделал проверку типа `!empty($wrd->num_rows)` и все работает. Спасибо за ответ.